# javascript - dynamically created textbox doesnt work as datepicker

Tags: javascript, datepicker

i created textbox dynamically by createElement and appendChild and i gave it a classname;
a fixed textbox in my code works as datepicker with it's classname property but the dynamically created textbox is not work as datepicker.

Comment: You need to initialize the datepicker _after_ you create the element.

Comment: If you post your code, we can show how to correct it.